# SOLR Haystack splitting numerics

Tags: solr, django-haystack

The question below relates to a Django application (1.8.8) using SOLR (4.9.0) and Haystack.

The data I need to search contains various strings such as "A1234" and "ABCDE1"; these strings will turn up in both "text" and "name" fields defined as follows:

```
name = indexes.CharField(indexed=True, model_attr="name")
text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
```

If one of the above strings is searched for in the text field then it won't be found, but there's no problem searching in the name field. If I omit the letter when searching in the text field (e.g. I search for "1234") then I can find what I'm looking for.

Querying the SOLR server directly with debugging enabled shows that these strings are split:

```
// text field - no hits
rawquerystring: "A1234",
querystring: "A1234",
parsedquery: "+text:a +text:1234",
parsedquery_toString: "+text:a +text:1234",
explain: { },
QParser: "LuceneQParser",

// name field - finds the correct records
rawquerystring: "name:A1234",
querystring: "name:A1234",
parsedquery: "name:a1234",
parsedquery_toString: "name:a1234",
explain: { },
QParser: "LuceneQParser",
```

The section of schema.xml relating to edge_ngram fields (the text field above being such) is as follows:

```
<fieldType name="edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1"        generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="
0" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

So, is there any means of preventing the split of these strings? I would have thought that the splitOnNumerics="0" option would have sorted the problem out (as suggested in [Solr: Can't search for numbers mixed with characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884338/solr-cant-search-for-numbers-mixed-with-characters)) but it appears that that cannot be applied to a solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory. I have used this latter factory because it got around another problem where a search for "foo bar" would not find "foobar.com" in the text field (users will be running this sort of search and expecting a hit).

Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. The edge_ngram field type contained this:

```
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />                                                                                              
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />                                                                                                   
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
```

Modifying the WordDelimiterFilterFactory to set generateNumberParts="0" did the trick whilst preserving the other requirements for this field.